# why this is not transitive yet a reflexive relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

The relation given is $ R = \{(a,b); 1ab>0; a,b ∈ R \} $

I clearly understand that this is symmetric since $a*b = b*a$ but I'm not able to understand that why is this *reflexive also* and not at all *transitive*. (Would be great if you can explain with the roster form of the given relation in set-builder form.)

Comment: This is incorrect.  $(0,0)$ is not in the relation.

Comment: On the other hand, it is transitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not reflexive. $0\times 0\not\gt 0$.

It IS transitive. If $ab \gt 0$ then $a,b$ have the same sign. If $bc\gt 0$ then $b,c$ have the same sign and thus $a,c$ have the same sign and $ac\gt0$.

Comment: So, that means that it is NOT reflexive and IS transitive. If that is the case, then the book that I'm consulting is probably not a good one. :-/